# Options(Plugins) in build section work for post build in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In jenkins, we have a requirement like having the options that appear under build step like (say)

1. Execute Shell
2. Execute commands over ssh
3. Invoke Ant

To appear in the post build section. And it should do the same work as it did under build section.

I made all the options in build section appear in UI under post build section by doing `it.getbuilddescriptors` in `config.jelly` of my plugin. And it appeared in my jenkins UI under post build section as a hetero list.

But the problem is I don't know how to make it work as a bost build step.

For shell we did

```
Shell s = new Shell(command);
s.perform(build, listener, launcher);
```

and it worked.

If this is possible, then it may even be possible for all build section items. Is there a direct way to do without doing as I did for 'Execute shell'?

Comment: Please explain the purpose of this setup. (If you wish to run the same commands twice, why not call another Job from the previous one and pass it the relevant parameters?)

Comment: We want to create a plugin that would do a complete deployment against the produce from each build or each job . This deployment may consist of running shell commands, running ant commands (mostly at the remote place) or  a war deployment (for which we have written a plugin with cargo).Mostly the deployment is a combination of all these . So we want to click the items in the hetero list , so that they appear in that order and then the user will fill the fields . Continued in next comment...

Comment: Cont....So if this feature is available as a single plugin we can attach it as a post build step for all the jobs and customize the deployment for each job as needed. We need this deployment as a post build, and not as a build step. As a number of steps involved here are in the build portion, we are in search to find ways to bring those options here,instead of writing a post build plugin for each.

Comment: You are trying to reinvent the wheel - all those "desired features" of you plugin are already available as working plugins - just need to trigger them from the existing jobs.

Comment: Are you speaking about the "conditional build step plugin " and "flexible publish plugin" ?

Comment: I usually get along with the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) which allows you to tie any 'Job' to an exiting one, thus splitting the build flow to steps.

Comment: Ya i completed by doing "conditional build step " plugin and changing it into a post build plugin . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider looking at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Any+Build+Step+Plugin

They provide ability to use Build Steps as Post-Build actions, and vice-versa